# TXSDateTime error "local time situated within the missing period prior to DST'

Tags: delphi, utc, dst, delphi-10-seattle

We convert our local dates (no time parts) to a external system expecting UTC datetime strings, by adding `TTimeZone.Local.UTCOffset` (now 2 hours) to a TDateTime.
This fails for the night we switch to DST (at 02:00).

Error from `System.RTLConst`:

```
SLocalTimeInvalid = 'The given "%s" local time is invalid (situated within the missing period prior to DST).';
```

occurring in `System.DateUtils`:

```
function TTimeZone.GetUtcOffsetInSeconds(const ADateTime: TDateTime; const ForceDaylight: Boolean): Int64;
var
  LOffset, LDSTSave: Int64;
  LType: TLocalTimeType;
begin
  { Obtain the information we require }
  DoGetOffsetsAndType(ADateTime, LOffset, LDSTSave, LType);

  { Select the proper offset }
  if (LType = lttInvalid) then
    raise ELocalTimeInvalid.CreateResFmt(@SLocalTimeInvalid, [DateTimeToStr(ADateTime)])
  else if (LType = lttDaylight) or ((LType = lttAmbiguous) and ForceDaylight) then
    Result := LOffset + LDSTSave
  else
    Result := LOffset;
end;
```

**Code to reproduce**:

```
function DateTime2UTCString(ADateTime: TDateTime): String;
var XSD: TXSDateTime;
begin
  XSD := TXSDateTime.Create;
  try
    try
      XSD.AsDateTime := ADateTime;
      Result := XSD.NativeToXS;
    except
      on E:Exception do
        Result := E.Message;
    end;
  finally
     XSD.Free;
  end;
end;

function Date2UTCString(ADateTime: TDateTime): String;
// Input is guaranteed to have no time fraction
begin
  ADateTime := ADateTime + TTimeZone.Local.UTCOffset;
  Result := DateTime2UTCString(ADateTime);
end;

procedure TFrmUTCandDST.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lDT: TDateTime;
  l  : integer;
begin
  lDT := EncodeDate(2016,3,25);
  for l := 0 to 2 do
  begin
    lDT := lDT +1;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(DateToStr(lDT) + ' -> ' + Date2UTCString(lDT));
  end;
end;
```

(Don't forget to use `SOAP.XSBuiltIns, System.DateUtils, System.TimeSpan`).

Output:

```
26-3-2016 -> 2016-03-26T02:00:00.000+01:00
27-3-2016 -> The given "27-3-2016 2:00:00" local time is invalid (situated within the missing period prior to DST).
28-3-2016 -> 2016-03-28T02:00:00.000+02:00
```

How can I graciously circumvent this? I can use `TTimeZone.Local.IsInvalidTime(ADateTime)` to detect invalid dates, **but**
`26-3-2016 2:00:00` would be wrong (that's exactly the time we moved to DST), **not** `27-3-2016 2:00:00` - so I don't know how to adjust in case of the 'invalid' date.

Comment: You should probably start thinking about where those times are coming from. And since those hours never existed, ask yourself why the system or application generated them. Once you know that you're probably close to understanding how you should cleanse that data. Is it in a database? Or a log? You most likely will have to move some of them forward an hour.

Comment: Like I wrote, they are dates. Sick days actually, no time fraction. They have to be wrapped into SOAP calls that create Exchange Server appointments. The appointments have property 'All day', hence the UTC strings have to specify things like 2016-03-28T02:00:00.000+02:00

Comment: Oh, and the database containing the sick dates has no idea of timezones.

Comment: If these are dates rather than times, why are you converting them at all?

Comment: @Davif Because Exchange Server is very finicky. If you want to create all-day appointments you have to specify start/end times in their exact format as UTC times (as commented above, where I forgot the trailing Z). Any deviation from that and either the appointment is no longer 'allday', or Outlook suddenly shows times in Reijkjavik time zone ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There is [bug in unit System.DateUtils.pas](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17649) (afaik still present in 10.1).

Function AdjustDateTime first takes date and time handling it as local time, and THEN tries to put offset into it. Since during daylight saving time there is a "missing hour" (in case of central Europe it was 26.03.2017), therefore after 1:59:59 A.M you've got 3:00:00 A.M.
If you accidentally use this period (like 2:17:35), you'll get an exception.

This is also present in other functions.

Simple code to reproduce the exception (C++):

```
ShowMessage(ISO8601ToDate("2017-03-26T02:22:50.000Z",false));
```

but this one runs ok:

```
ShowMessage(ISO8601ToDate("2017-03-26T02:22:50.000Z",true));`
```

For now to avoid the exception use XSD.AsUTCDateTime, then apply the local offset.
Example in c++ :

```
 TTimeZone * localTz = TTimeZone::Local;
 TDateTime TimeSomething = localTz->ToLocalTime(XSD->AsUTCDateTime);
```

In your case either local time is indeed invalid (there was no "2:00"),
or somewhere you're trying to treat UTC Time as local time, which of course is invalid. Solve this and you will solve your problem.

> How can I graciously circumvent this? I can use TTimeZone.Local.IsInvalidTime(ADateTime) to detect invalid dates, but 26-3-2016 2:00:00 would be wrong (that's exactly the time we moved to DST), not 27-3-2016 2:00:00 - so I don't know how to adjust in case of the 'invalid' date.

Additionally i think you missing that in year 2016 we moved to DST at 27.03 at 2:00 but THIS year at 26-03, so 27-3-2016 2:00:00 is perfectly invalid date :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Vancalar said, there is a bug in `ISO8601ToDate` when converting from UTC to local time near a DST transition.  **This bug persists in Rio 10.3.3.**

A simple workaround is to avoid `ISO8601ToDate`'s timezone conversion and let Microsoft do it.  That is, replace the `false` value with `true` and follow with a call to `UTCToTZLocalTime`, as in the following Pascal snippet:

```
// Get UTC datetime from ISO8601 string
datetime := ISO8601ToDate(ISO8601UTCstring, true);
// Convert to local time w/DST conversion
datetime := UTCToTZLocalTime(zoneinfo,datetime);
```